# I want to know why are two memory values provided for one variable M1?

Tags: memory, assembly, x86

```
M1  DB 10, 13, 'Enter the string : $'
```

please explain me lines?

```
    LEA BX,  BUFF+2
    MOV CH,  00H
    MOV CL,  BUFF+1
    MOV DI,  CX
```

HERE IS THE FULL CODE

```
.model small
.data
    M1  DB 10, 13, 'Enter the string : $'
    M2  DB 10, 13, 'String is palindrome $'
    M3  DB 10, 13, 'String is not palindrome $'
    BUFF    DB 80
        DB 0
        DB 80 DUP (0)
.code
START:  MOV AX, @data
        MOV DS,  AX
        MOV AH,  09H            ; Display message M1
    MOV DX,  OFFSET M1
        INT 21H
    MOV AH,  0AH        ; input the string
    LEA  DX,  BUFF
    INT 21H
        LEA BX,  BUFF+2
        MOV CH,  00H
        MOV CL,  BUFF+1
        MOV DI,  CX
        DEC di
    SAR CL,  1
        MOV SI,  00H
BACK:  MOV AL,  [BX + DI]       ; Get the right most character
        MOV AH, [BX + SI]       ; Get the left most character
    CMP AL,  AH
    JNZ  LAST
    DEC DI
    INC SI
    DEC  CL
    JNZ  BACK
        MOV AH,  09H            ; Display message 2
    MOV DX,  OFFSET M2
    INT 21H
    JMP  TER
LAST:  MOV AH,  09H
    MOV DX,   OFFSET M3     ; Display message 3
        INT  21H
TER:   MOV AH,  4CH
        INT  21H
        END START
```

Comment: Please provide some context, this makes no sence without more information and will likely be closed unless you [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19614601/edit)

Comment: SIR. I want to know why are two memory values provided for one variable M1?

Comment: When I asked for more context I meant stuff like: What language is this?, where did this line of code come from? Where did the variable M1 come from, how is it declared?, stuff like that.

Comment: this is an assembly language code...declaration of a variable M1 for storing string "ENTER THE STRING"  which comes under DATA SEGMENT

Comment: Ok, now it makes more seance. Basically `M1` holds `10`, the value at `M1+1` holds `13`, `M1+2` holds `'E'`, `M1+3` holds `'n'`, `M1+4` holds `'t'`, and so on. The address of `M2` is really `M1+22`

Comment: thank you sir,very well explained :)

Comment: 10 is ASCII for Line Feed, 13 is ASCII for Carriage Return

Comment: please explain me these instructions for above code LEA BX,  BUFF+2
        MOV CH,  00H
        MOV CL,  BUFF+1
        MOV DI,  CX

Answer (score 1):

The point behind these lines of code:

```
LEA BX,  BUFF+2
MOV CH,  00H
MOV CL,  BUFF+1
MOV DI,  CX
```

`DI` is a 16 bit register. The code wants to load the length (a byte) stored in `BUFF+1` into `DI`. But you can't load a byte into `DI`. So it loads the byte into `CL`, makes `CH` equal to `00`, and then copies the result (`CX`) to `DI`.

So if `[BUFF+1]` contained the value 0x13, then `CX`, which is `CH` and `CL` combined, gets the value 0x0013, and then that's copied to `DI`.

The `LEA BX, BUFF+2` appears to be loading `BX` with the address of the first character in the buffer. `BX` is subsequently used as an index into the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

10 and 13 are the decimal values for line feed and carriage return.for more reference check out int 21 functions..
they are used for displaying the msg1 and msg2 in different lines
 all d best